# What does "genetic correlations" mean as opposed to just correlations?

Tags: genetics, statistics

I'm reading the paper ["Large-scale GWAS reveals insights into the genetic architecture of same-sex sexual behavior"](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/365/6456/eaat7693/tab-pdf). In Fig. 4 shows "Genetic correlations of same-sex sexual behavior with various preselected traits". This sentence confuses me. I understand that you could do a standard statistical analysis to find correlations between same-sex sexual behavior and various traits. What makes the way they are doing the correlations "genetic"?

(Note: This may be more of a statistics question than a bio question. Feel free to move it to a more relevant SE site.)

Comment: They cite reference 16: https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.3406 might be useful to you. I think the question is relevant here, we have some regular users who are well-versed in heritability studies.

Comment: I believe this may be more of an English language question than a stats or a bio question. I shall check the article once to verify.

Comment: Looks **off-topic?** to me, _this is an english language question, not a biology one,_ correlations are correlations are correlations, the addition of the word genetic is merely there to highlight the data set / type under current reference in the sentence & nothing more.

Comment: I disagree that it's about English language. The question is really "I understand the meaning of a correlation between phenotypes A and B; what is the meaning of a *genetic* correlation between A and B." That is, how do you have a "genetic correlation" between Same-Sex Sexual Behavior and Depression?

Comment: @BryanKrause : You've convinced me, where b4 I only thought it likely I'm now sure that this is definitely a language comprehension issue & not a legitimate biology question :) off topic then.

Comment: @Pelinore Then please do explain it: I'm not new to statistical analysis and even I'm somewhat confused what exactly they are presenting. Remi.b's answer helps but is still not quite convincing me. How do you define, mathematically, a genetic correlation between two phenotypes?

Comment: @BryanKrause : _"How do you define"_ : I don't, they do, & I've already explained why this is a language comprehension issue, there's no arcane meaning intended they simply say that any genetic correlations found with same sex behaviour may (or may not) also correlate in some degree with other traits, it seems to me that any misunderstanding is simply what we might call a minor senior moment.

Comment: @BryanKrause : 'genetic correlations' in this instance simply means any correlations between genes (or genetic markers) & same sex behaviour it doesn't have any special or specific meaning as compared to ordinary correlations of any other data sets. So it's an English language question not a biology question.

Comment: @Pelinore No, that isn't true. Please read the paper. Depression is not a gene. Same sex behavior is not a gene. If you want a genetic correlation between depression and same sex behavior you have to define what that means. A correlation between genes and same sex behavior is understood and is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @BryanKrause it actually is about the language. The correlation that is being studied may be between two different conditions but the measured RVs, in this case are the genetic markers. That doesn't make "genetic correlation" a special kind of analysis. One can as well study the neurophysiology in these conditions and use the term "neurophysiological correlations". In both cases, the right phrase would be *correlation of (genetic) markers between conditions X and Y*.

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a correlation where one of the two variables considered is the genetic state at a given locus. In a GWAS, one loops through all loci and systematically performs a correlation analysis between the genetic states at this locus and the phenotypic trait of interest.

In the example of sentence you cite

> Genetic correlations of same-sex sexual behavior with various preselected traits

They looped through each polymorphic locus in their data set and at each locus they performed a correlation analysis between the two variables "genetic states at a this locus" and "same-sex sexual behavior" (whichever way this second variable is recorded).

A study might also be interested in more than one phenotypes. In such case, different phenotypic variables can either be considered separately or can be included in the same analysis through linear models. It is for example not so unusual to include one of the variable as a covariatiate in an ANCOVA type of design.

Comment: I think this answer is not quite complete (in the context of the paper OP is referring to)...I'd have to look closer but it seems there is an additional step, because they are talking about two traits and a genetic state, not one trait. I still think you are much better positioned to write the complete answer here, though. :)

Comment: I am too lazy to read the paper :D I added a little paragraph about cases where more than one phenotype is considered.

Answer (score 0):

I quote from [this paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/645945v5.full):

> Genetic correlation analysis can separate between shared additive genetic and environmental factors by using the genetic similarity between individuals (monozygotic twins have ∼100% and dizygotic twins and siblings ∼50% genetic similarity). To compute the genetic correlation between two traits the phenotypic correlation is decomposed in genetic and environmental sources of covariance using a maximum likelihood approach in combination with the genetic proximity matrix of the sample 34, 35. Additionally, the heritability of both traits is established to compute the relative contribution of genetic and environmental factors to the phenotypic correlation.

In the same paper you will also find some hints on how it is computed. However, if you want to go into further detail, I suggest you investigate the work of Laura Almasy and John Blangero. They did a lot of work on variance component analysis of QTLs. I remember using their software (SOLAR, which is now SOLAR-Eclipse) for computing genetic correlation in a work, but right now I am not able to find the paper in which they describe computation of genetic correlation.